# Css3 rotation, how to give depth

Tags: css, animation, rotation

I'm trying to make a coin flip animation using css3 but I can't figure out how to give the coin depth, since without depth it disappears once it's at 90 degrees which is unsightly, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the property perspective.
The perspective has to be apply to the father element of the one you are rotate it.

```
.parent {
   perspective: 1000px;
}

.child {
   transform: rotateY(50deg);
}
```